# Rejoining joined table in same query SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a query like following

```
SELECT * 
FROM   abc 
       FULL OUTER JOIN def 
                    ON ( abc.year = def.year 
                         AND abc.id = def.id )
```

And i need to apply another join on the result of above query so can i do it in single query or i will have to use subquery in this. 
I dont want to use subquery as my original query is already having 3 subqueries so is there any solution available for this situation

If i do it like this

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM   abc 
           FULL OUTER JOIN def 
                        ON ( abc.year = def.year 
                             AND abc.id = def.id ) 
LEFT JOIN xyz ON (abc.time=xyz.time)
```

Will it take the results of full outer join or only abc table

Comment: Does `def` table have a `time` column?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> create table t1 (id1 int, name1 varchar(10));
> create table t2 (id2 int, name2 varchar(10));
> create table t3 (id3 int, name3 varchar(10));
> insert into t1 values (1, 'aaa');
> insert into t1 values (2, 'bbb');
> insert into t1 values (3, 'ccc');
> insert into t2 values (1, 'xxx');
> insert into t2 values (2, 'yyy');
> insert into t2 values (3, 'zzz');
> insert into t3 values (1, '111');
> insert into t3 values (4, '222');
> insert into t3 values (5, '333');
> ```

Considering only this 3 tables it doesn't matter if you use a single query or a subquery with a LEFT JOIN. The result is the same.

But in your question you say:

> my original query is already having 3 subqueries

Without the whole query it is difficult to know.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM   t1
> FULL OUTER JOIN t2
> ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
> LEFT JOIN t3
> ON t3.id3 = t1.id1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID1 | NAME1 | ID2 | NAME2 |  ID3 | NAME3
> --: | :---- | --: | :---- | ---: | :----
>   1 | aaa   |   1 | xxx   |    1 | 111  
>   3 | ccc   |   3 | zzz   | null | null 
>   2 | bbb   |   2 | yyy   | null | null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (SELECT *
>       FROM   t1
>       FULL OUTER JOIN t2
>       ON t1.id1 = t2.id2) tt
> LEFT JOIN t3
> ON t3.id3 = tt.id1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID1 | NAME1 | ID2 | NAME2 |  ID3 | NAME3
> --: | :---- | --: | :---- | ---: | :----
>   1 | aaa   |   1 | xxx   |    1 | 111  
>   3 | ccc   |   3 | zzz   | null | null 
>   2 | bbb   |   2 | yyy   | null | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02639e9526412ff6fb59cc1b95a2bc7d)*